# Linking an Angular directive attribute to its template as a class with Jade

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, pug

I'm trying to pass my custom Angular directive an attribute in its markup and have that attribute be assigned as a class in one of the containers of that directive's template.

Here's how my input would look, in Jade:

```
.form-layout-group
  short-text-input.item(label="Short Input Group", inputColumnsClass="short-text-2")
```

Here's the function that returns my directive:

```
function ShortTextInput (FormControlService) {
  restrict: 'E',
  replace: true,
  require: ['^validationForm', '?ngModel', '^?formCollection'],
  scope: {
    inputColumnsClass: '@'
  },
  templateUrl: '/templates/input/shortTextInput/short-text-input.html',
  link: FormControlService.link
})
```

In my template, I'm trying the following:

```
include ../../input/_input-mixins.jade

+WrapInputwithLabelAndErrorplaceholder
  div.inner-icon
    div(class="{{ inputColumnsClass }}")
      +InputwithValidation.item
```

Unfortunately, I'm not able to get this columns class to show up and actually style the input in my preferred method. When I hardcode this class into my template, what I'm intending to do works just fine.

Any tips on how I should be approaching this?

Comment: Yep, that was exactly it! Can't believe I missed it.

Comment: @estus write an answer with that information so it can be accepted and seen easily for future users.

Comment: @ArianFaurtosh Sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `input-columns-class="short-text-2"`.

`input-columns-class` DOM attribute is [normalized](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$compile.directive.Attributes#$normalize) to `inputColumnsClass` camel-case form by `$compile` service, while `inputColumnsClass` DOM attribute is normalized to `inputcolumnsclass`.